# Drop down list of Images from reactivemongo demo app GridFS

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

... for each article.

Get Image name and Image (reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue) and put it in a form select?

https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app

Does anyone know how to do this?

The application is based on Play 2.1

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "drop down list"?

Comment: form select (all images for document)